# Using information about covariance between ARIMA models in forecasting

Tags: forecasting, arima, simulation, covariance-matrix, forecast-combination

I'm interested in how to incorporate information about the covariances of related timeseries from multiple univariate forecasts into each forecast. The ultimate goal of this is to implement hierarchical forecasts with prediction intervals, I am not considering a VAR here, I thought that this merited a separate simulation question as it is sufficiently general as to be of wider interest. I will link to the other question when I've written it up.

I want to check that the following approach works, that is, if there are statistical issues with this approach. I've tried to keep the code readable and am only really worried about it insofar as there's a statistical issue.

I have two correlated time series, the data here are just for the purposes of an example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(hts)
library(MASS)

exampledata <- aggts(htseg2)[,c("A","B"])
ally <- data_frame(exampledata[,"A"], exampledata[,"B"])
```

I fit models to each of the series, and build a variance-covariance matrix of the residuals - in this I think I am following the estimation strategy of this paper: https://robjhyndman.com/publications/mint/ , in particular page 11, method 4.

```
allr <- matrix(NA, nrow = 16, ncol = ncol(ally)) 
for(i in 1:ncol(ally)){
  allr[,i] <- auto.arima(ally[,i])$residuals
}

fullcovmat = matrix(c(cov(allr)),
                    nrow=2, ncol=2)
```

Variance-Covariance matrix of residuals:

```
# inspecting the matrices

fullcovmat
fullcovmat %>% cov2cor
```

I can now simulate from the residuals using mvrnorm, assumption being that the residuals are jointly normally distributed, perhaps the assumption of joint normality here is too strong, I understand that without specific data only horoscopic advice can be given on this.

```
intervalsone <- matrix(NA, nrow = 1000, ncol = 10)
intervalstwo <- matrix(NA, nrow = 1000, ncol = 10)

# simulating 1000 times, for each simulation 2 columns of 10 values are
# pulled from the multivariate normal to replace the rnorm residuals

a = auto.arima(ally[,1]) 
b = auto.arima(ally[,2])
for(j in 1:1000){
  simulations = mvrnorm(10, rep(0,2), Sigma = fullcovmat)
  intervalsone[j, ] <- simulate(a, future = TRUE, innov = simulations[,1])
  intervalstwo[j, ] <- simulate(b, future = TRUE, innov = simulations[,2])
}

# putting the simulation intervals together

ints <- matrix(NA, nrow = 3, ncol = 10)
ints2 <- matrix(NA, nrow = 3, ncol = 10)

for(i in 1:10){
  ints[,i] <- sort(intervalsone[,i])[c(25,500,975)]
  ints2[,i] <- sort(intervalstwo[,i])[c(25,500,975)]
}

# plotting the simulated values and the output from forecast for a 95% PI
# and the median (simulations in red)

par(mfrow = c(1,2))

plot(forecast(auto.arima(ally[,1]), level = 95))
for(i in 1:3){
  lines(ints[i,] %>% unlist %>% ts(start = 17), col = "red")
}

plot(forecast(auto.arima(ally[,2]), level = 95))
for(i in 1:3){
  lines(ints2[i,] %>% unlist %>% ts(start = 17), col = "red")
}
```

[image]

Comment: Two issues  .. 1) assumption of normality of the residuals is very questionable in my experience even after intervention detection is used to identify anomalies  2 ) assumption that anomalous observations in the past WILL NOT happen in the future

Comment: I understand the first point, however I'm less clear about the second, is this because the residuals from the model fit are only used to determine the variance-covariance matrix for the simulations? Thinking about how to proceed, perhaps I should be considering copulas? Or would a bootstrapping approach resolve this? I am aware of this paper which uses bootstrapping to preserve the correlation between residuals from each series: http://www.cpc.ac.uk/publications/cpc_working_papers/pdf/2013_WP40_Grouped_Time-Series_Forecasting_Shang_et_al.pdf

Comment: I was referring to the introduction of empirically identifiable anomalies into the monte-carlo simulation of forecasts for each time series for each origin.