# Building the covariance matrix for hts prediction intervals

Tags: forecasting, arima, covariance-matrix

In my previous question: [Using information about covariance between ARIMA models in forecasting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/300905/using-information-about-covariance-between-arima-models-in-forecasting) I was interested in the more general case of how to use the covariance matrix in prediction intervals once it has been obtained. Here I am trying to produce the prediction intervals for hts forecasts using the covariance matrix from the paper https://robjhyndman.com/publications/mint/. I'd like to check that I've interpreted the paper correctly.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(hts)
library(MASS)
library(hts)
library(SparseM)
library(Matrix)

exampledata <- aggts(htseg2)[,c("A","B")]
exampledataobject <- hts(exampledata)
ally <- aggts(exampledataobject)
ally
allr <- matrix(NA, nrow = 16, ncol = ncol(ally)) 

for(i in 1:ncol(ally)){
  allr[,i] <- auto.arima(ally[,i])$residuals
}
```

In order to produce prediction intervals for the hts forecasts I need to produce **Var[y<sub>t+h</sub>-yhat<sub>t</sub>(h)] = SPW<sub>h</sub>P'S'** (page 7 and Lemma 1 in the appendix), I have altered the code from https://github.com/earowang/hts/blob/master/R/tracemin.R. This code normally produces equation 9 on page 8 of the paper above.

In order to produce **SP** I remove the multiplications with fcasts. I have also checked **P** by computing it according to the computationally intensive method (equation 7) and it is the same. GmatrixH and Smatrix code is also taken from the hts package Github to produce gmat and smat. Beyond the changes to the CHOL function the rest of this code is directly from the hts package to produce gmat and smat.

```
CHOLTWO <- function(S, weights) {
  nts <<- nrow(S)
  nbts <<- ncol(S)
  nagg <<- nts - nbts
  seqagg <- 1L:nagg
  utmat <- cbind(methods::as(nagg, "matrix.diag.csr"), -1 * S[1L:nagg, ])
  jmat <<- methods::new("matrix.csr", ra = rep(1L, nbts), ja = seq((nagg + 1L), nts),
                        ia = 1L:(nbts + 1L), dimension = as.integer(c(nbts, nts)))
  rhs.l <- utmat
  if (is.null(weights)) {
    lhs.l <- utmat %*% t(utmat)
    lhs.l <- (t(lhs.l) + lhs.l)/2
    lin.sol <- backsolve(chol(lhs.l), rhs.l)
    p1 <- jmat - (jmat %*% t(utmat) %*% lin.sol)
  } else {
    lhs.l <- utmat %*% weights %*% t(utmat)
    lhs.l <- (t(lhs.l) + lhs.l)/2
    lin.sol <- backsolve(chol(lhs.l), rhs.l)
    lin.sol <- matrix(lin.sol, nrow = 1) # added so that this doesn't become a vector in this instance
    p1 <- jmat - (jmat %*% weights %*% t(utmat) %*% lin.sol)
  }
  comb <- as.matrix(S %*% p1)
  return(comb)
}

nodes <- get_nodes(exampledataobject)

GmatrixH <- function(xlist) {
  l.xlist <- length(xlist)
  num.bts <- sum(xlist[[l.xlist]])
  nlist <- unlist(lapply(xlist, length))
  # Create an empty matrix to contain the gmatrix
  gmat <- matrix(, nrow = l.xlist, ncol = num.bts)
  # Insert the bottom level
  gmat[nrow(gmat), ] <- seq(1L, num.bts)
  # Insert the middle levels in the reverse order
  if (l.xlist > 1L) {
    repcount <- xlist[[l.xlist]]
    for (i in (l.xlist - 1L):1L) {
      gmat[i, ] <- rep(1L:nlist[i + 1], repcount)
      repcount <- rowsum(repcount, rep(1L:nlist[i], xlist[[i]]))
    }
  }
  # Insert the top level
  gmat <- rbind(rep(1L, num.bts), gmat)

  dimnames(gmat) <- list(paste("Level", 0L:(nrow(gmat) - 1L)), colnames(xlist))
  class(gmat) <- "gmatrix"
  return(gmat)
}

gmat <- GmatrixH(nodes)

Smatrix <- function(gmat) {
  # Sparse matrices stored in coordinate format
  # gmatrix contains all the information to generate smatrix
  num.bts <- ncol(gmat)
  sparse.S <- apply(gmat, 1L, function(x) {
    ia <- as.integer(x)
    uniq.g <- unique(ia)
    ra <- as.integer(rep(1L, num.bts))
    ja <- as.integer(1L:num.bts)
    s <- as.matrix.csr(new("matrix.coo", ra = ra, ja = ja, ia = ia,
                           dimension = as.integer(c(length(uniq.g), num.bts))))
  })
  sparse <- do.call("rbind", sparse.S)
  return(sparse)
}

smat <- Smatrix(gmat)
n <- nrow(ally)
w.1 <- crossprod(allr)/n
weights <- as.matrix.csr(w.1)
```

I can then multiply this by **w.1** (defined for MinT here: https://github.com/earowang/hts/blob/master/R/MinT.R) and **S'P'** to produce the variance-covariance matrix required.

```
y4.f <- CHOLTWO(smat, w.1)
covmat <- y4.f %*% w.1 %*% t(y4.f)
```

This code then produces the intervals and plots in the manner of my question: [Using information about covariance between ARIMA models in forecasting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/300905/using-information-about-covariance-between-arima-models-in-forecasting)

```
intervalsone <- matrix(NA, nrow = 1000, ncol = 10)
intervalstwo <- matrix(NA, nrow = 1000, ncol = 10)
intervalsthree <- matrix(NA, nrow = 1000, ncol = 10)

a = auto.arima(ally[,1]) 
b = auto.arima(ally[,2])
c = auto.arima(ally[,3])
for(j in 1:1000){
  simulations = mvrnorm(10, rep(0,3), Sigma = covmat)
  intervalsone[j, ] <- simulate(a, future = TRUE, innov = simulations[,1])
  intervalstwo[j, ] <- simulate(b, future = TRUE, innov = simulations[,2])
  intervalsthree[j,] <- simulate(c, future = TRUE, innov = simulations[,3])
}

# putting the simulation intervals together

ints <- matrix(NA, nrow = 3, ncol = 10)
ints2 <- matrix(NA, nrow = 3, ncol = 10)
ints3 <- matrix(NA, nrow = 3, ncol = 10)

for(i in 1:10){
  ints[,i] <- sort(intervalsone[,i])[c(25,500,975)]
  ints2[,i] <- sort(intervalstwo[,i])[c(25,500,975)]
  ints3[,i] <- sort(intervalsthree[,i])[c(25,500,975)]
}

par(mfrow = c(1,3))

plot(forecast(auto.arima(ally[,1]), level = 95))
for(i in 1:3){
  lines(ints[i,] %>% unlist %>% ts(start = 2008), col = "red")
}

plot(forecast(auto.arima(ally[,2]), level = 95))
for(i in 1:3){
  lines(ints2[i,] %>% unlist %>% ts(start = 2008), col = "red")
}

plot(forecast(auto.arima(ally[,3]), level = 95))
for(i in 1:3){
  lines(ints3[i,] %>% unlist %>% ts(start = 2008), col = "red")
}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you got any further with this? It looks like Rob Hyndman hasn't implemented the long awaited prediction intervals for hts yet?

Comment: I'm sure you wrote a detailed response to this - but can't see any trace of it now! Did I dream it?!

Comment: Sorry, I did post a response but reading it over I felt that it could be a bit more focused. Because you have a base forecast for every node in your group or hierarchy, and then the adjustments reconcile the forecasts across all of these  by making the smallest adjustments, I think the normality of residuals in your univariate forecasts should give you a good indication as to how big an assumption that is for your prediction intervals. I'll edit to include these intervals built without simulation when I get time. Interested to hear your thoughts on this or anything in the above.

Comment: Yes I agree that 'the normality of residuals in your univariate forecasts should give you a good indication as to how big an assumption that is for your prediction intervals'. Tbh I'm a total novice in this sort of stuff, so really I'm not able to offer much opinion beyond that. It feels like this functionality would be a useful addition to hts, so if there's a way I can help get the code up and running (with some pointers from you) then I'm definitely keen to do that. Shall we open an issue on the hts github?